# Avoiding infinite loops in two-way data binding

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a datetime picker element defined in Polymer like so:

```
# CoffeeScript
Polymer
  is: "date-picker"

  properties:
    # External getter/setter string interface
    startTime:
      type: String
      notify: true

    # Internal representation
    _startTime:
      type: Object
      notify: true
```

The internal representation is because I'd like to maintain a Moment.js object that represents the `startTime`. I would like `_startTime` to be updated when `startTime` is set from an external source, and `startTime` to be updated when `_startTime` is changed. Is there a way to do this without creating an infinite loop? For example, with Backbone.js I would achieve this by passing a parameter to not fire update events.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pointed out to me on the helpful Polymer Slack channel. Wrap the updates around flags to prevent processing caused by update events.

Like so:

```
# CoffeeScript
Polymer
  is: "date-picker"

properties:
  startTime:
    type: String
    notify: true
  _startTime:
    type: Object
    notify: true

listen:
  "startTime-changed": "onStartTimeChange"
  "_startTime-changed": "onIntStartTimeChange"

onStartTimeChange: (e) ->
  if not @_isProcessing
    @_isProcessing = true
    @set("_startTime", moment(e.detail.value))
    @_isProcessing = false

onIntStartTimeChange: (e) ->
  if not @_isProcessing
    @_isProcessing = true
    @set("startTime", e.detail.value.format())
    @_isProcessing = false
```